# Is there a console-like API for Windows Store?

Tags: .net, api, console, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

So I have a design that would greatly benefit from a console. By console, I mean

1. User inputs text
2. I take the input
3. I return the output on the next line
4. User enters more text on the line after and repeat

Now, I'm NOT looking for ways to access the Win32 console APIs, but rather a Console library or some such for Windows Store implemented in XAML or some such.

I remember very clearly seeing a project that did all this, but I can't find it now. So, is there a library or some such out there like this, preferably open source?

Answer (score 2):

It exists and is the Console class for Modern UI Apps. It is a pay product

http://www.moderncomponents.com/products/ConsoleClass/index.php

It uses  similar syntax to write out console data, ie

```
Console.WriteLine("yourdata");
```

Comment: Pretty creepy, seeing somebody spell "Framewrok" is a turn off.  Can you document this beyond the shopping link?  For example, is this library known to pass the Store validation procedure?

Comment: @HansPassant they "say" they pass. I contacted their sales, but haven't received a reply yet. Also, all of the APIs are async, which I wouldn't really think would make sense for a console and very prone to race conditions. If it's cheap though, it probably will work for me